# Select only required columns using native SQL query in spring boot

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i have integrated a native query in spring Data JPA which basically selects all the child's and its parent folder.

```
class Folder{
      int x;
      int y;
      int z;
    }
```

i am trying to select only few columns and every time i do it i am getting error saying X column is missing.Below is the example.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name tpc_msc10_project_id was not found in this ResultSet.
```

In the repository layer i have written a native query to get all the child folders along with parent folder.

```
 @Query(nativeQuery=true,value="select x,y from folder with some condition")
        List<Folder> getAllChildFoldersByParentFolderId(@Param("folderId")Integer folderId);
```

So,is it not possible to select only few columns from the Resultset using native query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interface based [projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces) for native query as well as for regular JPQL query:

```
public interface FolderProjection {
    Integer getX();
    Integer getY();
}

@Query(value = "select f.x as x, f.y as y from folders f where f.id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<FolderProjection> getFolderProjection(Integer folderId);
```

Note the aliases (f.x as x), which are necessary for the trouble-free work of the method...

Comment: This seems to be interesting..will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that:

```
@Query(value = "select handle from table_name where handle like 'DN%' order by handle desc limit 1", nativeQuery = true)
String getMaxTempHandle();
```

Comment: i am confused.Do you mind replicating in the query scenario i mentioned? with the return type Folder?
 @Query(nativeQuery=true,value="select x,y from folder with some condition")